Failed loading controller
When I try to launch the real_robot.launch.py in my PC, the controllers joint_state_broadcaster and my custom controller mobilebot_controller configured correctly without any error. But when I try the same thing using my Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 22.04 server with ROS2 Humble it shows error message:
[ros2_control_node-2] [ERROR] [1714558663.893747146] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'joint_state_broadcaster'.    
[ros2_control_node-2] [ERROR] [1714558663.895819943] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'mobilebot_controller'.   
[spawner-3] [FATAL] [1714558663.997426619] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed loading controller joint_state_broadcaster    
[spawner-4] [FATAL] [1714558663.997426601] [spawner_mobilebot_controller]: Failed loading controller mobilebot_controller   
[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 1504, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].    
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 1506, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner mobilebot_controller --ros-args'].

my controller yaml file is
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100
 
    
 
  joint_state_broadcaster:
    type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
 
    
  mobilebot_controller:
    type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
 
 
mobilebot_controller:
  ros__parameters:
 
    #type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
    use_stamped_vel: true
    left_wheel_names:  ['left_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
    publish_rate: 50.0
    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 0.01]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 0.01]
 
    wheel_radius: 0.034
    wheel_separation: 0.365
    left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
 
    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
 
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    publish_limited_velocity: true
    publish_wheel_data: true
    enable_odom_tf: true
 
    linear:
      x:
        has_velocity_limits: true
        max_velocity: 1.0
        min_velocity: -0.5
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration: 0.8
        min_acceleration: -0.4
        has_jerk_limits: false
 
    angular:
      Z:
        has_velocity_limits: true
        max_velocity: 1.7
        min_velocity: -0.5
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration: 1.5
        min_acceleration: -1.5
        has_jerk_limits: false


    

mobilebot_controller.launch.py
import os

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():

    wheel_radius_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "wheel_radius",
        default_value = "0.034"
    )

    wheel_separation_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "wheel_separation",
        default_value = "0.365"
    )

    wheel_radius = LaunchConfiguration("wheel_radius")
    wheel_separation = LaunchConfiguration("wheel_separation")

    
    

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"]
    )

    mobilebot_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["mobilebot_controller"]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        wheel_radius_arg,
        wheel_separation_arg,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        mobilebot_controller_spawner,
    ])

hardware_interface.launch.py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
from launch.substitutions import Command

import xacro



def generate_launch_description():

    robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(["xacro ",os.path.join(
                                                get_package_share_directory("my_mobilebot"), "description", "robot.urdf.xacro"
                                                )]),
                                                value_type=str)
    
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[{"robot_description": robot_description}]
    )

    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[
            {"robot_description" : robot_description,
             "use_sim_time": False},
            os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory("mobilebot_controller"),
                "config",
                "mobilebot_controllers.yaml"
            )]
    )





    return LaunchDescription([
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        controller_manager,
    ])


 

real_robot.launch.py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():

    hardware_interface = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory("my_mobilebot"),
            "launch",
            "hardware_interface.launch.py"
        )
    )
    

    controller = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory("mobilebot_controller"),
            "launch",
            "mobilebot_controller.launch.py"
        )
    )

    velocity_converter_node = Node(
        package="mobilebot_firmware",
        executable="velocityconverter.py",
        name="velocityconverter",

    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        hardware_interface,
        controller,
        velocity_converter_node,

    ])

Please help me to solve this issue

Welcome at RSE. Please take your time to properly format your question the next time.
Back to your question: The error means that something is missing with your parameters: The type (under namespace controller_manager) has to be known to the controller_manager before the spawner is executed. If your code format was correct, then there is a wrong indent of joint_state_broadcaster and mobilebot_controller: It has to be below ros__parameters and not at the same level.
And be aware that the yaml is case sensitive: you have angular.Z instead of angular.z, what might cause other problems.
You can use tools like [rqt_reconfigure][1] to see if all parameters are properly set.
[1]: https://index.ros.org/p/rqt_reconfigure/github-ros-visualization-rqt_reconfigure/#humble
